# How to associate the column title with the column values from an HTML document with R and XPath?

Tags: r, xpath

I have parsed with R an HTML document which looks like this:

```
<table>
<b>title1</b>
<tr>row1</tr>
</table>
<table>
<b>title2</b>
<tr>row2</tr>
<tr>row3</tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to get my HTML document parsed with R in order to have such a table:

```
title    |    value
title1   |    row1
title2   |    row2
title2   |    row3
```

I've tried something with this code:

```
doc<-htmlParse(html_document)
titles<-sapply(getNodeSet(doc,"//table//b"), function(x) xmlValue(x))
values<-sapply(getNodeSet(doc,"//table//tr"), function(x) xmlValue(x))
```

But it doesn't work, as title is composed with 2 different values (title1 and title2) and values with 3 different ones (row1, row2 and row3) and I can't associate row1 with title1 and row2 and row3 with title2.

I'm sure there is a solution but I don't manage to find it. Could you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it will help you

```
//table//*[name()='b' or name()='tr']
```

returns

```
Element='<b>title1</b>'
Element='<tr>row1</tr>'
Element='<b>title2</b>'
Element='<tr>row2</tr>'
Element='<tr>row3</tr>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very ugly answer which does not use XPath but... it works:

```
tabledir=getNodeSet(doc,"//table")
#returns a list of all the nodes inside the successive <table>
parsed=matrix(nrow=0,ncol=2)
indice=NULL
for(i in tabledir){
 if(grepl("<b>",toString.XMLNode(i))){ #select "title" nodes
  indice=xmlValue(i) 
 }
 else
 {
  valeur=c(indice,xmlValue(i))
  parsed=rbind(valeur,parsed)
 }
}
```

Ugly isn't it? I'm still sure there is a way to do it with XPath.